# Callable/runnable/function with param returning void?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

- `Callable<R>` takes no arguments and returns `R`.
- `Runnable` takes no arguments and returns `void`.
- `Function<T, R>` takes an argument, `T`, and returns `R`.

What about a function that takes an argument and returns void? What is this analog called in Java?

Comment: i may be wrong on this but I'm pretty sure you can use `void` as a generic argument in Java.

Comment: [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html)

Comment: @aeskreis `java.lang.Void` could be used for this.

Comment: `void` as a type param seems a bit hacky. I was looking for `Consumer` -- thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). It has one input and returns `void` with method `Consumer::accept(T t)`.

> Represents an operation that accepts a single input argument and returns no result.

There is its variation called [`BiConsumer<T, U>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) which turns 2 inputs into `void`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). It is a functional interface that takes a single argument and returns void.

Answer (score 1):

It's called Consumer, it's a function that takes an argument(or more), does something and doesn't return anything.
For example, if you use a forEach:

```
exampleList.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```